# SSIS Derived column padding of leading zeroes

Tags: if-statement, ssis, expression, padding, ternary-operator

I want to be able to add leading zeroes in following scenarios -

1. I need leading zeroes before [ACCOUNT ID] if [ACCOUNT ID] < 17 {For APPLICATION = RCC, SEC, HOGAN CIS}
2. I need leading zeroes before [ACCOUNT ID] if ([ACCOUNT ID] + [ACCOUNT NUMBER]) < 17 {For APPLICATION = CLN}
3. I need leading zeroes before [CLIENT KEY] if ([CLIENT KEY] + [CLIENT ID]) < 17 {For APPLICATION = ITF}

I have the following expression defined in my derived column -

```
 LTRIM(RTRIM(APPLICATION == "RCC" || APPLICATION == "SEC" ? APPLICATION + "|" + [ACCOUNT ID] : APPLICATION == "HOGAN CIS" ? (HOGAN_Hogan_Alpha_Product_Code == "DDA" ? "DDA" : "TDA") + "|" + [ACCOUNT ID] : APPLICATION == "ITF" ? APPLICATION + "|" + [CLIENT KEY] + [CLIENT ID] : APPLICATION == "CLN" ? APPLICATION + "|" + [ACCOUNT ID] + [ACCOUNT NUMBER] : APPLICATION + "|" + [ACCOUNT NUMBER]))
```

Answer (score 9):

### Padding strings

The general strategy I use when dealing with adding leading characters is to always add them and then take the N rightmost characters. I find it greatly simplifies your logic.

```
RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 17) + [MyColumn], 17)
```

That would generate 17 zeros, prepend that to my column and then slice off the last 17 characters. If MyColumn was already 17 character, then no effective work is done. If it was empty, now you have a value of 17 zeros.

### Choosing

In your case, I'd first try add a derived column to identify which block of logic this `APPLICATION` falls into. Much like the existing ternary expression you have.

```
(APPLICATION == "CLN") ? 10 : 
    (APPLICATION == "ITF") ? 20 :
    (APPLICATION == "RCC" | APPLICATION == "SEC" ....) ? 30 : 40
```

Coming out of that derived column, you'll be able to verify the logic is working as expected which makes the padding an easier scenario.

Comment: Thanks @billinkc - Can I not implement RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 17) + [MyColumn], 17) rightaway in my expression? What is the harm in it? The logic applies same to all applications - just that for some applications, like ITF, the padding has to be done BEFORE  CLIENT KEY if combination of CLIENT KEY and CLIENT ID is less than 17.

Can I not implement something like RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 17) + [CLIENT KEY + CLIENT ID], 17)

Comment: You *can* but the reason for my advocacy of breaking this out is for future maintainability. There are no facilities in SSIS for evaluating a misfiring Expression so the less you do in one, the easier it becomes to set a data viewer between two components and look for where things have gone wrong. In 2012, you can also set a data tap to capture this.

Comment: Alright thanks billinkc, let me try this and I will update the thread.

Comment: below expression gives syntax error.

LTRIM(RTRIM(APPLICATION == "RCC" || APPLICATION == "SEC" ? APPLICATION + "|" + RIGHT(REPLICATE("0", 17) + [ACCOUNT ID], 17) : APPLICATION == "HOGAN CIS" ? (HOGAN_Hogan_Alpha_Product_Code == "DDA" ? "DDA" : "TDA") + "|" + RIGHT(REPLICATE("0", 17) + [ACCOUNT ID], 17) : APPLICATION == "ITF" ? APPLICATION + "|" + RIGHT(REPLICATE("0", 17) + [CLIENT KEY] + [CLIENT ID], 17) : APPLICATION == "CLN" ? APPLICATION + "|" + (RIGHT(REPLICATE("0", 17) + [ACCOUNT ID] + [ACCOUNT NUMBER], 17) : APPLICATION + "|" + RIGHT(REPLICATE("0", 17) + [ACCOUNT NUMBER], 17)))