# Azure SQL to DB2 data migration via SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, db2, etl, azure-sql-server

I want to create an SSIS package with source as azure sql and destination as DB2 table.
I have to check if Id (int) in sql matches with Id (X12 basically varchar) in DB2, if it matches, I have to update name in db2 with the name in SQL
else insert new record in DB2.

Since, datatype of id does not match, I have to do a data type conversion- that is if id in sql is 1 .. I have to convert it to varchar with leading zeros - 00000000001
Can some one please provide a step by step approach?
and where exactly can I make this conversion.. in which task?

Comment: Hi, did you try using derived column transformation to add leading zeros (**ex: RIGHT("0000000000"+[Id],10)**)? please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22303528/ssis-derived-column-padding-of-leading-zeroes) if this is of any help.

Comment: `SELECT FORMAT (1, REPLICATE ('0', 11))`?

Comment: If DB2 is on Azure you can use Azure Data Factory. It's quite straight forward: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server?tabs=data-factory